# Am I overusing sass extend here?

Tags: css, sass, extend

I'm using  `sass %extend` with `display:flex` for the sake of cross browser compatibility and I ended up with this long list of nested elements in my css file just for the flexBox.

the styling :

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
```

Is this alright or is this an overuse of %extend and if so what is the best practice.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](https://csswizardry.com/2014/11/when-to-use-extend-when-to-use-a-mixin/) will help you. And as Thushar suggested, you can also go with a common class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is good practice because if you want to use this property you write like this

```
For Example: 
.row{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
nav .container{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
nav form{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
nav form .input-group{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
nav ul:first-of-type{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
.sr-buttons.internal{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
.main-form .status{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
.main-form .status>aside>ul:first-child{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
.main-form>ul{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
.main-form>ul>li{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
.publish{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
.publish>div{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
.publish>div>ul{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
.publish>div>div{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
.publish.active>div>ul>li{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}

One more option you can use like this:
.commonFlex{display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build cross browser compatibility style with sass. many way to do this. One way of creating mixin. first you create a mixin like this:

```
@mixin display-flex($important: '') {
    @if $important == '' {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
    } @else {
        display: -webkit-box $important;
        display: -moz-box $important;
        display: -ms-flexbox $important;
        display: -webkit-flex $important;
        display: flex $important;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this mixin with using `@include` like this

```
.row {
    @include display-flex;
}
```

OR

```
.row {
    @include display-flex(!important);
}
```

If you want to extends this. you can

```
%display-flex {
    @include display-flex;
}
.row {
    @extend %display-flex;
}
```